# Angular firing function in then clause before original function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-promise

I've got a list of service calls that I can call all at the same time, but I have 1 other call that MUST be called, and completed before the others get fired off. I set this up so the other calls didn't occur until the `.then(function() {})` block of the call. Checking Chrome Dev Tools (and getting confirmation based on the Sql error), all of the calls in the then clause are firing before. What am I doing wrong here?

```
        var promises = [];

        if (this.partner.customerId > 0) {
            if (this.isDirty('ipn.individualPartnerName')) {
                promises.push(this.partnerEditService.updateIndividualName(<Interfaces.IIndividualPartner>this.partner));
            }

            if (this.isDirty('bpa.mailingAddressForm') || this.isDirty('bpa.streetAddressForm')) {
                promises.push(this.partnerEditService.updateAddresses(this.partner));
            }

            if (this.isDirty('bn.businessName')) {
                promises.push(this.partnerEditService.updateBusinessName(<Interfaces.IBusinessPartner>this.partner));
            }

            if (this.isDirty('rc.individualPartnerResponsibilities') || this.isDirty('rc.businessPartnerResponsibilities')) {
                promises.push(this.partnerEditService.updateResponsibilities(this.operation, this.partner));
            }
        }

        this.partnerAddRepository.addExisting(this.operation.operationId, this.partner.customerId)
            .then(() => {
                this.executeSaves(promises);
            });


    executeSaves = (promises) => {
        this.$q.all(promises)
            .finally(() => {
                this.$mdDialog.hide(this.partner);
            });
    }
```

And here's the partnerAddRepo.addExisting function:

```
    addExisting = (operationId: number, partnerId: number) => {
        return this.$http.put(`my/path/to/operation/${operationId}/partner/${partnerId}`);
    };
```

So, the stuff in the `executeSaves`, which contains the 4 different service calls are being called BEFORE the `partnerAddRepository.addExisting` call gets fired, why?

Comment: Uh, care to explain the downvote.

Comment: Could it be timing?  You are pushing those promises into the array, but also firing whatever returns the promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service calls are executed as soon as you call them. Promises defer the return value of the function call, not the function's execution.

If you want to call the other function only after `partnerAddRepository.addExisting` has returned a value, then you should create the array of promises in the `then` callback.

```
this.partnerAddRepository.addExisting(this.operation.operationId, this.partner.customerId)
    .then(() => {
        var promises = [];

        if (this.partner.customerId > 0) {
            if (this.isDirty('ipn.individualPartnerName')) {
                promises.push(this.partnerEditService.updateIndividualName(<Interfaces.IIndividualPartner>this.partner));
            }

            if (this.isDirty('bpa.mailingAddressForm') || this.isDirty('bpa.streetAddressForm')) {
                promises.push(this.partnerEditService.updateAddresses(this.partner));
            }

            if (this.isDirty('bn.businessName')) {
                promises.push(this.partnerEditService.updateBusinessName(<Interfaces.IBusinessPartner>this.partner));
            }

            if (this.isDirty('rc.individualPartnerResponsibilities') || this.isDirty('rc.businessPartnerResponsibilities')) {
                promises.push(this.partnerEditService.updateResponsibilities(this.operation, this.partner));
            }
        }

        this.executeSaves(promises);
});
```

Comment: perfect sir, thank you. Never would have thought that I'd need to nest that entire chunk in the .then()

Comment: I would probably put that chunk in a function, and only call that function. This way the `then` is less messy